# In a sequence do all voices need to be sequential?

Tags: voice-leading

In the examples I have in my text book all the voices seem to move in a sequential pattern except maybe at the cadence where there might be an alteration in the soprano but what if an iteration of the sequence was to be modified and a different voicing was used. Would this matter or does each iteration in the sequence need to use the same voicings?

[image: realization of I-V6-vi-iii6 sequence]

I started writing a descending 3rds sequence here but you can see my chord voicings change. Does this mean that this is not a sequence or is the root movement what matters?

Answer (score 1):

It does matter. The example given shows a *harmonic sequence* — that is, the underlying chords move in a sequential pattern — but not a *melodic sequence* — in which each voice moves sequentially.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Are these sequences used mostly as harmonic and melodic sequences or is a harmonic sequence also very common with a varying melody. I want to incorporate some sequences in a few of my own compositions but I find the repitition in all the voices a bit too much so I just wanted to use the sequence for the harmony and then write a melody on top that is a bit more interesting and not so repetitive.

Comment: @armani Are you asking if purely harmonic sequences are common and/or valid? Yes, both. Otherwise, you'll have to clarify your question for me.